# Cypress & TypeScript - Array of viewport devices - 'ViewportPreset' type

Tags: arrays, typescript, foreach, cypress, viewport

I'm trying to loop over an array of strings in order to use the same logic for all tests but for different device sizes. However I can't figure out how to make TypeScript happy with the type for 'ViewportPreset'. Here is how the test file looks:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
const dimensions = ["iphone-xr", "samsung-s10"];

context("check responsiveness", () => {
  dimensions.forEach((dimension) => {
    it("check responsiveness", () => {
      cy.viewport(dimension); // <- error
    });
  });
});
```

Error that I'm getting: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ViewportPreset'.ts(2345)`. I tried to do something like `const dimensions : ViewportPreset[] = ["iphone-xr", "samsung-s10"];` but it response with `Cannot find name 'ViewportPreset'.ts(2304)`. The only solution I currently have is to use `any[]` but I think `any` should be generally avoided since it removes all the benefits of TypeScript in first place. Also, if I add one of the dimensions manually to `cy.viewport()`, even tho it's a string, I get no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly tell the callback that `dimension` is a ViewportPreset.

Note small c on types="cypress" is the convention, but it does not seem to matter here.

Include the Cypress namespace in the type.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

context("check responsiveness", () => {
  dimensions.forEach((dimension: Cypress.ViewportPreset) => { 
    it("check responsiveness", () => {
      cy.viewport(dimension); 
    });
  });
})
  ...
```

Also this works (instead of above)

```js
const dimensions: Cypress.ViewportPreset[] = ['iphone-6', 'ipad-2']
```